# Can Cloudflare's Origin CA certificate can be used for local HTTPs in Caddy?

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, caddy

I have a Cloudflare Origin CA certificate that I use in my Caddy config for various subdomains that point to services running on my home server that are exposed to the internet. I was wondering if it's possible to use the same certificate with locally defined subdomains  that point to local services that I do not want exposed to the internet. by "locally defined subdomains" I mean those configured on my local DNS server that don't actually exist on the actual cloudflare's DNS dashboard. e.g. `pihole.mydomain.com`.

Caddy has this `tls internal` option but unless I copy the root CA from Caddy server to all the machines on my network I get the following warning when trying to access them in a browser.

[image]

I tried `tls /etc/ssl/cloudflare.pem /etc/ssl/cloudflare.key` and I get the same warning message. The cloudflare's origin CA does have the `*.mydomain.com` wildcard so I thought I could just use it locally for subdomains that are not configured in my cloudflare DNS panel. Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: **Cloudflare's origin CA** does not meet CABforum requirements and thus **is not trusted by browsers** unless you add it manually (your 'copy root to all machines'). It is designed only to be trusted by Cloudflare itself, when CF edge servers access your origin (backend) server. See https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/ . And this isn't really programming or development.